# Searching in the Ubuntu Software manager

Tags: software-center, search

I am a Ubuntu newbie, though I have briefly used Mint.  I want to find how to search by name for available-to-download software through the software center.  Can I ask how i do this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A search box will be appear on the top right corner in Ubuntu software center.Type the software name you want to search on the search box.

[image]

If the software you searched,was not available on software center then you have to update the software repositories by running the below command on terminal,

`sudo apt-get update`